# Numeros que no se repitan en los arreglos JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, array

Estoy haciendo un programa de capturas donde un profesor ingresa su clave, si la clave no ha sido registrada anteriormente entonces puede registrar su nombre pero si ya esta registrada saldra un mensaje diciendo "error". Sin embargo, no soy muy buena en los arreglos y banderas ya que no entiendo muy bien el concepto y por consecuencia mi programa tiene el error de deja registrar el nombre del profesor aunque esa clava ya este registrada. Que estoy haciendo mal?

```js
var menu_opcion;
var profesores_opcion;
var profesor= [];
var x;
var profesor1;
var renglon=0;
var error=0;
var nombre=[];
do{
menu_opcion=prompt("Ingrese la opcion deseada \n 1)Profesores \n 2)Grupo \n 3)Alumnos \n 4)Reportes \n 5) Calificacion \n 6) Salida")
if(menu_opcion==1)//PROFESORES
{
  profesores_opcion=prompt("MENU PROFESORES \n1)Captura \n2)Consultas \n3)Cambios ")
  if(profesores_opcion==1)
  {
    do{
      error=0;
        renglon=renglon+1;
  profesor1=prompt("Registro Numero :"+  renglon+ "\nIngrese su clave")
     for(x=1; x<=renglon; x++)
               {
                  if(profesor1==profesor[x])
                  {
                     error=1;
                  }
                  if(error===0)
                  {
                    nombre[x]=prompt("Ingrese su primer nombre")
                  }
                  if(error===1)
                  {alert ("Numero ya registrado")
                    
                  }
                  }
               
   
    }while(error!==0)
  }
  
}
}while (menu_opcion!=6)
```

Comment: Has intentado usar objetos con propiedades? mira este [articulo de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos)

Answer (score 0):

El problema muy seguramente es en

```
if(profesor1==profesor[x])
{
   error=1;
}
```

pues en ningún lado veo que al array `profesor` se le asigne algún valor, por ello no se ejecuta y continúa a

```
if(error===0)
{
   nombre[x]=prompt("Ingrese su primer nombre")
}
```

Luego, hay muchas cosas en el código que se podrían mejorar:

1. Trabaja con funciones, incluso si lo requiere utiliza clases.
2. En caso de varias sentencias **if - else** existe la alternativa **switch**.
3. No entiendo muy bien para qué el `for`, si es para buscar en un *array*, sería mejor con `indexOf` o alguna otra función.
4. Si en un `if` asignas el valor a una variable y luego en otro `if` comparas ese valor, sería mejor juntarlos en uno, esto específicamente por:

```
if(profesor1==profesor[x])
{
   error=1;
}
if(error===0)
{
  nombre[x]=prompt("Ingrese su primer nombre")
}
if(error===1)
{alert ("Numero ya registrado")

}
```

Que sería mejor:

```
if(profesor1==profesor[x])
{
   error = 1;
   alert ("Numero ya registrado")
}
if(error===0)
{
  nombre[x]=prompt("Ingrese su primer nombre")
}
```