# Bucle infinito en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Por alguna razón en mi programa se está generando un bucle infinito y este no me permite correrlo.

```js
var menu_opcion;
var profesores_opcion;
var profesor = [];
var x;
var profesor1;
var renglon = 0;
var error = 0;
var yaesta = 0;
var nombre = [];
var primer_apellido = [];
var activo = 0;
var renglon = 0;
var auxnombre;
var auxa_primerapellido;

do {
    yaesta = 0;

    menu_opcion = prompt("1. Proferores \n2.Grupo \n3.Alumnos \n4.Reportes \n5.Calificacion \n6.Salida ");
    do {
        if (menu_opcion == 1) {
            profesores_opcion = prompt("1. Captura \n2.Consultar \n3.Cambios \n4.Cancelaciones\n5.Salida")
            if (profesores_opcion == 1) {
                renglon = renglon + 1;
                do {
                    error = 0; //la variable error se iguala a 0 para evitar un bucle infinito.
                    profesor1 = prompt("Ingrese su clave" + "\n" + "Registro no.: " + renglon)
                    for (x = 1; x <= renglon; x++) {
                        if (profesor1 == profesor[x]) {
                            error = 1;
                            alert("Profesor ya registrado")
                        }
                    }
                } while (error !== 0);

                if (error != 1) {
                    profesor[renglon] = profesor1;
                    error = 0;
                    auxnombre = prompt("Ingrese su nombre")
                    nombre[renglon] = auxnombre.toUpperCase();
                    primer_apellido[renglon] = prompt("Ingrese su Primer apellido")
                    primer_apellido[renglon] = aux_primerapellido.toUpperCase();

                    activo[renglon] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    } while (profesores_opcion != 5)
} while (menu_opcion != 6)
```

Comment: te han enseñado funciones?

Comment: La pregunta no es es clara. Falta que describas que hace el código, en particular lo que pretendes que hagan los do...while y cómo es que esperas que funcionen las condiciones de estos.

Comment: ¿Es esta una pregunta de seguimiento de [Numeros que no se repitan en los arreglos JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/87917/65)?

Answer (score 2):

Solo sales del bucle interno si `profesores_opcion` es `5`, pero solo asignas un valor si `menu_opcion` es `1`.

De hecho, la secuencia 1-5-6 sale sin ningún problema (en la primera iteración del bucle interno asignas el valor de `profesores_opcion` a `5`, que sigue existiendo en la segunda iteración del bucle interno).

Solución: Hay que asegurarse de que la lógica interna no te dé ningún caso donde la expresión del bucle sea `true` pero los valores de los que depende esa expresión no se pueden modificar. Por ejemplo, añadir un `else` a `if (menu_opcion == 1)` que asigne `5` a `profesores_opcion`<sup>1</sup>.

En todo caso la estructura es rara. Lo más normal sería meter el bucle dentro del `if (menu_opcion==1)`, de forma que sólo se entrara en el bucle que depende del valor de `opcion_profesor` en el caso de que `opcion_profesor` tenga sentido.

Adicionalmente:

- Con un par de `alert` y `console.log` investigando los valores de las variables en cada punto importante probablemente habrías encontrado el problema tú misma; en el peor de los casos la pregunta se habría podido responder de immediato.
- Como insinúa @ArieCwHat, el código empieza a ser bastante inmanejable (y como prueba, el hecho de que no pudieras leer correctamente lo que hace). Empieza a usar funciones o cada vez será peor (y nadie por aquí te va a ayudar a depurar un código de 200 líneas).

---

<sup>1</sup>Hay que tener cuidado con no tener en cuenta sólo los valores que esperamos, sino todos los posibles. Es decir, no basta con cubrir las posibilidades "válidas" (1-5) sino también todas las posibles (un usuario puede escribir "20" o "hola", y el programa no debería colgarse).